# Which iOS IPSW file is the right one for my iPhone 5S?

Tags: ios

I installed iOS 10 beta 1 on my iPhone 5S but now I'd like to go back to the release version of iOS 9.3.2.

When I go to download the IPSW file for iOS 9.3.2 from www.ipsw.me I am presented with two types of IPSW file, one for "iPhone 5S (Global)" and one for "iPhone 5S (GSM)".

Which file should I use? The only other information I can add is that I bought the phone in the UK.

Comment: Does this help? https://discussions.apple.com/thread/5107732?start=0

Comment: Downloading versions of iOS from anywhere but Apple is a bad idea. To downgrade to iOS 9.3.2, see this: http://www.gottabemobile.com/2016/06/14/how-to-downgrade-ios-10-beta-to-ios-9-or-ios-9-3-2/

Comment: The trick is to look for the existing ipsw file (use EasyFind, free App Store) & match the model number 6,1 or 6,2. I think UK should be 6,2

Comment: @RedEagle2000 The website ipsw.me provides direct links to Apple's download servers.

Answer (score 1):

As you can see from the ipsw.me website Apple have released two slightly different versions of iOS 9.3.2 for the iPhone 5S. By looking at Apple's developer website I can see that one version is for iPhone models A1453, and A1533 and that the other is for models A1457, A1518, A1528, and A1530.

Unfortunately the ipsw.me website does not directly identify which IPSW is which, but by selecting each of them in turn we can see their file names. These file names contain the hardware string for the kind of iPhone they should be installed on.

- iPhone 5S (GSM): iPhone6,1_9.3.2_13F69_Restore.ipsw
- iPhone 5S (global): iPhone6,2_9.3.2_13F69_Restore.ipsw

According to [this website](https://www.theiphonewiki.com/wiki/Models):

- Models A1453, A1533 = iPhone6,1
- Models A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530 = iPhone6,2

You'll [find your iPhone's model number](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201296) on the back of the case (it will start with "A1").

- A1453, A1533 and you need the (GSM) IPSW from www.ipsw.me
- A1457, A1518, A1528, A1530 and you need the (global) IPSW from www.ipsw.me